# Why bash background task ignores SIGINT?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, sigaction

I noticed that `sleep` can't be killed by SIGINT when spawned by:

```
(sleep 1000 &)
```

I wonder why is so. 
All of the following are killed by SIGINT:

```
sleep 1000
sleep 1000 &
(sleep 1000)
( ( (sleep 1000) ) )
( ( (sleep 1000)& ) )
```

so I figure it must have something to do with non-interactive bash (brackets are required to enter subshell) and task have to be run in the background. 
I wrote a short C program to test the behaviour and found that sa_handler is set to SIG_IGN -- explaining phenomenon, but why exactly is so? 
I haven't found any information whether it is an intended feature (though considering length of manual I may have simply missed it) and if so, what was the reason behide it. 
I include the C code for those interested:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <signal.h>

int main() {
    struct sigaction oldact;
    if(sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &oldact) != 0) {
        printf("Error in sigaction\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(oldact.sa_flags & SA_SIGINFO) {
        printf("Using sa_sigaction\n");
    } else {
        if(oldact.sa_handler == SIG_DFL) {
            printf("Default action\n");
        } else if(oldact.sa_handler == SIG_IGN) {
            printf("Ignore signal\n");
        } else {
            printf("Other action\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
[pilcrow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627836/11298974) is great and I accepted it. I wanted to add as to *why* posix says so that, according to [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) both SIGINT and SIGQUIT are *from keyboard*. So it kinda makes sens to ignore them in processes detached from one (and not job controled by bash).
EDIT2:
Checkout [Mark Plotnick comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626955/why-bash-background-task-ignores-sigint/60627836?noredirect=1#comment107288481_60627836) for true explanation WHY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construct, `(sleep 1000 &)` puts your *sleep* command in a grandchild subshell with no job control:

```
your-shell
      \
      a compound-list in a subshell
          \
         an asynchronous list in a subshell
```

The first subshell, *( compound-list )* (a [grouping command construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01)), simply runs the backgrounded *command &* (an [asynchronous list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02)) and then exits.  The asynchronous list is run in its own subshell.

That final subshell is too far removed from your initial shell for job control to be meaningful.

Per POSIX, ["[i]f job control is disabled ... when the shell executes an asynchronous list, the commands in the list shall inherit from the shell a signal action of ignored (SIG_IGN) for the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals."](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11)

Thus your *sleep* is run with SIGINT set to ignore.

Comment: I don't understand why add such a tricky case. Is there a reason behind this inheritance? Since job control is out of question why bother to change process default behaviour?

Comment: @yjay If job control is disabled, the shell will not bother creating a new process group for each command. If you run an asynchronous command (&) and type control-C to the shell, both the shell and the asynchronous command will receive SIGINT. This would normally terminate the asynchronous process, so the shell does the sensible thing and makes such processes ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT.