Sending SIGINT to background process does not stop it
Given following script (work.sh)
#! /bin/bash

must_stop=""
function sigint_handler()
{
    echo "SIGINT"
    must_stop="1"

}
trap sigint_handler SIGINT

COUNTER=0
while [ -z "${must_stop}" ]
do
    ((COUNTER+=1))
    echo "#${COUNTER} Working..."
    sleep 1
done

I have executed it as a background process: $ sh -c "work.sh &"
Now,I wanted to stop it with SIGINT (simulating Ctrl+C when running in foreground), for that I did:
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14125 pts/3    00:00:00 tcsh
27717 pts/3    00:00:00 work.sh
28288 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep
28605 pts/3    00:00:00 ps

$ kill -INT 27717

but it continues printing counter (no echo "SIGINT" and no stop), why? What is the right way to stop it with SIGINT (not SIGTERM/SIGKILL)?

Does this answer your question? Interrupt sleep in bash with a signal trap

The answer is probably to replace sleep 1 with sleep 1 & wait. Since sleep ignores SIGINT, your script may choose not to handle the signal when it sees that sleep exited normally.

tjm3772 Trieed, that didn't help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626955/why-bash-background-task-ignores-sigint wow

@KamilCuk thanks, can you please elaborate how can I stop the process in such a situation (I can not SIGKILL it because in my real-life problem, it creates additional processes)?

trap SIGUSR1 and send SIGUSR1

As it was mentioned by KamilCuk,
according to signal(7) manual both SIGINT and SIGQUIT are from keyboard. So it makes sense to ignore them in detached processes. We need to use another signal (e.g. SIGUSR1)
#! /bin/bash

must_stop=""
function sigint_handler()
{
    echo "SIGUSR1"
    must_stop="1"
    exit 1
}
trap sigint_handler SIGUSR1

COUNTER=0
while [ -z "${must_stop}" ]
do
    ((COUNTER+=1))
    echo "#${COUNTER} Working..."
    sleep 1 &
    wait $!
done

